# Problems executing Perl scripts from PHP

Tags: php, shell-exec

Trying to figure this out. I am trying to execute a perl script within php, using shell_exec() like so:

```
<?php
$output=shell_exec("./tst.pl > test.txt");
//$output=shell_exec("./tst.pl");
echo $output;
?>
```

It will not write output to a file using ">" filename.txt.
It will work if I execute without directing it to a filename as I can confirm this with echo.

Does this have to do with using ">"?
Permissions should be fine as I am able to run the same perl script on command line and direct to file. Any suggestions for executing this?

The output of "test.txt" will be used as input:

```
<?php 
$data = array(); 
$InputFile = file("test.txt");
...
?>
```

Comment: If php is run by a webserver it might have different permissions

Comment: good point. i am running this in dev and i'm executing this as root. so i would think that would work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was definitely a permissions problem. Wrote the file out to /tmp and it worked fine.

```
<?php
$output=shell_exec("./tst.pl > /tmp/test.txt");
echo $output;
?>
```