# post access using file_get_contents doesn't solve 411 error on using content length

Tags: php, http

I'm trying to access post data using `file_get_contents`, however I get the following error message:

`failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 411 Length Required`.

Although I used `Content-Length field` the error doesn't get solved. Here is my code if someone can help me, thanks in advance.

```
<?php
set_time_limit(0);
include "ui.php";
$oy= `perl E:/mul.pl`;
$context  = stream_context_create(array('http' => array('method'=>'POST', 'header'  => 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded', 'Content-Length: 0', 'content' => '')));
$result = file_get_contents($oy, false, $context);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use [apache_note](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.apache-note.php) and [virtual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.virtual.php) php function for run perl

or see this page's  for execute perl by php shell functions

[Execute perl in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11114277/execute-perl-in-php)

[How can I call a Perl script from PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3733844/how-can-i-call-a-perl-script-from-php)

[using shell_exec to call a perl script from php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5971554/using-shell-exec-to-call-a-perl-script-from-php)

[Problems executing Perl scripts from PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3481121/problems-executing-perl-scripts-from-php)